# Changing value of data frame based on another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Again I need your help for a maybe easy question that is not clear for a starter R user.

I need to manipulate a dataframe to substitute `NA` values by "realistic" ones to feed another application.

The data frame contains values of -3.0 that was the flag for non valid values in the original data base. What I need is to replace all the -3.0 values by data coming from another data frame, or maybe to interpolate.

The first data frame would be

```
1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2.0  3.0 -3.0 -3.0
1.0  4.0 -3.0  6.0
1.0  5.0  4.0  5.0
```

the second one would be

```
1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2.0  2.0  9.0  9.0
2.0  2.0  9.0  2.0
1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

and the expected result

```
1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2.0  3.0  9.0  9.0
1.0  4.0  9.0  6.0
1.0  5.0  4.0  5.0
```

I suppose this can be done with a for loop but I haven't found the way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quite simple to do this without a for loop: if your data frames are `A` and `B`, then the command would be

```
A[A == -3] = B[A == -3]
```

In other words: for all the indices of `A` that have value -3, assign the values of `B` at the corresponding indices.

Comment: Thanks for so a fast answer, it perfectly works. Sorry, seeing it was so simple I should have investigated more in basic R commands