# Replace rows in one data frame if they appear in another data frame

Tags: r

I have the following two data frames:

df1

```
id   V1 V2 V3
210  4  NA 7
220  NA NA NA
230  2  0  1
240  4  NA NA
250  1  9  2
260  6  5  NA
270  0  NA 3
```

df2

```
id   V1 V2 V3
210  4  3  7
240  4  3  NA
270  0  3 3
```

df2 is all the instances where df1 has NA in V2 and at least one numeric value in V1 or V3. Where this condition holds, I have changed the NAs in V2 to '3'.

I would now like to put these dfs back together. Specifically, I would like to replace all the rows in df1 that appear in df2. My expected output is this:

```
id   V1 V2 V3
210  4  3 7
220  NA NA NA
230  2  0  1
240  4  3 NA
250  1  9  2
260  6  5  NA
270  0  3 3
```

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305312/changing-value-of-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame), but it does this based on specific values in the df. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411231/r-replace-rows-in-a-data-frame-based-on-criteria) is similarly answered by specifying the actual values to replace. My real df is huge and all I want to do is put the two dfs together, replacing the rows that appear in both with df2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple `match` call that will identify the instances that match `df2$id` within `df1$id` (in the correct appearance order) will solve this problem

```
df1[match(df2$id, df1$id), ] <- df2
df1
#    id V1 V2 V3
# 1 210  4  3  7
# 2 220 NA NA NA
# 3 230  2  0  1
# 4 240  4  3 NA
# 5 250  1  9  2
# 6 260  6  5 NA
# 7 270  0  3  3
```

---

Edit:
As @plafort points out, you could avoid creating `df2` in the first place, but I would go with vectorized approach instead of using `apply`. For example

```
indx <- rowSums(is.na(df1)) != (ncol(df1) - 1) & is.na(df1$V2)
df1[indx, "V2"] <- 3
```

Comment: is there any way to do this with dplyr or equiv?

Comment: @StephanieOwen What is wrong with this solution? Is it slow? Is it hard to read? In other words why is the tool more important than the cause?

Comment: Because my supervisor is really irritating and for some reason is obsessed with our lab group using the dplyr library and functions for all coding regardless of whether it works or not. nothing wrong with the solution itself 

dplyr functions are generally a little more readable though

Comment: This is the most elegant solution I've ever seen because it's simple. One can always create a dummy variable and delete it when the task is done.

Answer (score 5):

I had a matching syntax similar to @DavidArenburg with

```
df1[df1$id %in% df2$id, ] <- df2
```

Could it help to not have to create the extra data frame? If `df2` is being created to fill in `df1`, you can quickly assign `3` to the appropriate regions without creating a new dataframe.

```
indx <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) is.na(x[3]) && any(!is.na(x[2:4])))
df1$V2[indx] <- 3
df1
   id V1 V2 V3
1 210  4  3  7
2 220 NA NA NA
3 230  2  0  1
4 240  4  3 NA
5 250  1  9  2
6 260  6  5 NA
7 270  0  3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs dataframes to match in several columns using the using df1[match(dfid, dfid), ] <- df2 solution, as was my case, I used this trick

```
  df1$aux1<-paste(df1$id1,df1$id2) 
  df2$aux1<-paste(df2$id1,df2$id2) 
  df1[match(df2$aux1, df1$aux1), ] <- df2
  df1 <- df1[ , names(df1)!="aux1"]
```

This is probably very obvious, and not elegant, but it works